# script exited with error status 127

Tags: centos, bash, centos6, linux-networking, iproute

i wrote some scrip for setting route on specific interface on linux (CentOS 6.0)
and put them into Networkmanager script path (/etc/Networkmanager/dispatcher.d)
with highest prefix number.(i give execution permition too.)

this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" == "eth1" ]] && [[ "$2" == "up" ]]
then
    ip route add 192.XX.XX.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.XX.XX.XX table eth1
    #logger scrip run.
fi
```

but when eth1 is up i see this error on my syslog-message list:

```
localhost nm-dispatcher.action: Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-eth' exited with error status 127.
```

can anyone say where is my mistake??

Comment: i found that, i should use "ip" command with whole path like "/sbin/ip" in this script.

Comment: You can also `source /etc/profile` to avoid issues like that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I'll have to reply.

Error 127 means that either command used is not found *or* your script is not +x.
More info from advanced bash-scripting guide at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html